# Use google script to add an address autocomplete section to google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Within the google forms there is an option to create a custom add-on using google script. Through this method is it possible to create an address lookup using google API as documented here?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Comment: Forms add-ons run in the editor, not the live form.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification,  it's a shame it doesn't work

Comment: You can do some Regex to validate input in the live form, but thats about it.

Comment: Adding this for reference as work round not solution/answer. Used the validate data function to ensure postcode entered was correct (UK use only) then included an optional question with link to what3words encouraging users to copy paste the result into the form. It's then easy to strip this back and get the long / lat position

Comment: Addendum to the above if you don't mind leaving google forms then jotform allows you to plugin to google's API for address autocomplete and map display with adjustable marker. You can still output results to google sheets. It's free to paid service depending on scale of response.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as @Spencer-Easton comment. You can't. But you can achieve the same result through jotform or a work round as the comments